# Change audio speed then save as new file

Tags: javascript, audio

Is there anyway I can programmatically change the playback speed of an audio file with javascript and save it as a new file?

The only solution I can think of is to pipe the audio file through a web audio api node, alter the playback rate, and record the output as a wav file. This is not ideal though because I would have to play the file all the way through in order to record the new version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [offline audio context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext) (Web Audio API) to process the audio.
This processes the audio, without having to wait for real-time playback.

```
//will hold the sped up audio
var spedUpBuffer;

//Create the context 
var offlineCtx = new OfflineAudioContext(2,44100*40,44100);//(channels,length,Sample rate);

//create source node and load buffer
var source = offlineCtx.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = yourBuffer;

//speed the playback up
source.playbackRate.value = 1.25;

//lines the audio for rendering
source.start(0);

//renders everything you lined up
offlineCtx.startRendering();
offlineCtx.oncomplete = function(e) {
//copies the rendered buffer into your variable.
spedUpBuffer = e.renderedBuffer;
}
```

Comment: do you know how to make the pitch normal? when we change AudioBufferSourceNode.playbackRate, the audio pitch is not corrected

Comment: @Jun Have you solved it? I encountered the same problem.