# How to record an audio from microphone, change the playbackRate and save it?

Tags: html, web-audio-api

I would like to record a voice from the microphone using HTML Web Audio API, change the playback rate and save it as a new blob or file.

I followed these suggestions on:
[How to create an AudioBuffer from a Blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40363335/how-to-create-an-audiobuffer-from-a-blob/60025223#60025223)
and:
[Change audio speed then save as new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904243/change-audio-speed-then-save-as-new-file)

I record with MediaRecorder, then parse the audio Blob with FileReader, finally I change the playback rate using OfflineAudioContext and try to get the new Blob and URL, but it seems like the file is an incorrect format.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code on CodePen:
https://codepen.io/carlo318/pen/vYvzBQY

Or a part of my code is here:

```
  var audioBlob = null;
  var eStream = null;
  var eMediaRecorder = null;
  function init() {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then((stream) => {
        eStream = stream;
        // Init
        eMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        let chunks = [];
        eMediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
          chunks.push(e.data);
        };
        // Stop event: get blob data
        eMediaRecorder.onstop = (e) => {
          audioBlob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/webm;codecs=opus" });
          chunks = [];
          const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
          // Set data to <audio> object
          $('#audio1').attr('src', audioURL);
          // Get Base64 to save later
          getAudioBase64();
          
          // Change playbackRate
          let audioContext = new AudioContext();
          let fileReader = new FileReader();
          fileReader.onloadend = () => {
            // Convert arrayBuffer
            let arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;
            // Obtain AudioBuffer
            audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, function (audioBuffer) {
              // Change playback rate and render new Blob
              let offlineCtx = new OfflineAudioContext(2, 44100 * 20 , 44100);
              let source = offlineCtx.createBufferSource();
              source.buffer = audioBuffer;
              source.playbackRate.value = 1.4;
              source.preservesPitch = false;
              source.connect(offlineCtx.destination);
              source.start(0);
              // Render new blob from audioBuffer with playbackRate changed
              offlineCtx.startRendering().then((renderedBuffer) => {
                const blob = new Blob(renderedBuffer.getChannelData(1), { type: "audio/webm;codecs=opus" });
                const url2 = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                console.log(url2);
                $('#audio2').attr('src', url2);
              }).catch((err) => {
                console.error(`Rendering failed: ${err}`);
              });
            });                            
          }
          fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(audioBlob);
  
        };
  
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(`getUserMedia error: ${err}`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Audio: getUserMedia not supported on your browser, or HTTPS required.");
    } 
  }
  
  init();
  
  function eRecord() {
    eMediaRecorder.start();
  }
  function eStop() {
    eMediaRecorder.stop();
  }
  
  function getAudioBase64() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(audioBlob);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
      var base64data = reader.result;
      $('#audio2').attr('src', base64data);
    }
  }
```

Thankyou.

I was expecting to listen to an audio with the voice changed in the second  tag, but the file is mute and it doesn't playback.